# Non protected broadcast causes crash on starting of app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-notifications, android-broadcastreceiver

I made a service for receiving notification, every time data is updated at the back end. Here's the code for the service:

```
public class FeedbackService extends IntentService {

public FeedbackService() {
    super("FeedbackService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("MyService", "About to execute feedback call");

    feedbackCheckCall(this);
}

private void feedbackCheckCall(final Context context){
  //Call for getting checking data from backend.

}

private void sendNotification(Context context) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Feedback Reply")
                    .setContentText("You've a reply waiting for your feedback!")
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{500,500,500});

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, navHomeActivity.class );
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}

}
```

Here's the code for the reciever :

```
public class FeedbackRecieiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent dailyUpdater = new Intent(context, FeedbackService.class);

    context.startService(dailyUpdater);

    Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "Called context.startService from AlarmReceiver.onReceive");
}
}
```

Here's the code from where I call it:

```
    Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    long intervalTime = 2*60*60*1000; //in milliseconds format is : h*m*s*1000

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, FeedbackRecieiver.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,updateTime.getTimeInMillis(),intervalTime,pendingIntent);
```

My manifest declarations are :

```
 <service android:name=".navFragments.feedbackSuppport.FeedbackService"/>
 <receiver  android:name=".navFragments.feedbackSuppport.FeedbackRecieiver"/>
```

The app is crashing when I use a signed copy with this error on startup:

```
 Sending non-protected broadcast com.motorola.motocare.INTENT_TRIGGER from system 6836:com.motorola.process.system/1000 pkg com.motorola.motgeofencesvc
                                               java.lang.Throwable
                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18179)
                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:18779)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:512)
                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2905)
                                                   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

Can someone please help me out with this? I'm really stuck here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that error is from your app? Nothing in your code seems to refer to that broadcast.

Comment: @CommonsWare This is the latest code I've added to my application. I don't see why it would be something else. It works fine when I'm testing it via usb live copy. What else do you think it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there was no issue with broadcast receiver or the service. The issue was while using proguard. I was not using it correctly. I had disabled it in the debug variant and enabled it in the release variant. The app was crashing due to that.

Comment: I solved it by disabling the proguard. If you want to implement proguard, go through the android guides and online available content.

Comment: This happens even in DEBUG, where no Proguard is in effect... I doubt that Proguard is the root cause.